# CentOS 5.6 unexpected inconsistency how to repair?

Tags: filesystems, centos5, corruption, fsck

This morning I found that my server was not responding and wasn't able to connect to it in anyway to do a safe reboot. I had to do pull the plug to reboot. Upon rebooting everything appeared to be normal up till booting CentOS. Below is a screenshot of what I have.

[image: CentOS file system error]

The HDD's are not reporting any errors so this appears to me that something has corrupted. I haven't a clue what to do next. How can I get this system back up and running?

The server is only used as an rsync offsite backup drive. Reinstalling is an option but only as a last resort as the server is holding 1TB of backup data and to re-sync that it would take a month to do over our office connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've experienced some filesystem corruption. From where you are, you can probably run `fsck -y /` to kick off the process of filesystem repair, based on the image you attached. The `-y` answers yes to the questions the `fsck` command will probably output. Try this first.

Comment: running `fsck` now. This may take some time...

Comment: Well? What happened with it?

Comment: repaired and up and running. need to check all services are still working